# Coordinates conversion from X,Y to Lat,Long

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, format-conversion

I'm coding an android app based on an webservice which is already built and running (not mine, it's a public one). 
My problem is that it is return really weird coordinates to every spot.
Example:
The webserver is returning this coordinates from this spot (São Luiz - Teatro Municipal , which is a portuguese theatre):

X: -1017715.4315
   Y: 4680103.68

And according to google maps, the coordinates should be this:

Lat: 38.708935
   Long: -9.142481

I think it's another coordinates format, but i'd really appreciate if some one could tell me how can I convert it to the "normal" format, so I can input it to Google maps in android.

Comment: If it's a public one, which one is it and where is the documentation to tell you which coordinate system is returned?